# How to merge two raw query in Django 2?

Tags: django, python-3.x, merge

I was trying to merge two query return data, into one object like

```
viewAllUq = Uqmain.objects.raw('''
                select *, uqmain.id as uqmainID, company.name as companyName, uqmain.created_by as uqMainCreated_by, 
                    company.slug as companySlug, uqmain.slug as uqmainSlug from uqmain 
                Left join company ON company.id = uqmain.company_id 
                Left join user ON user.id = uqmain.created_by 
                where uqmain.deleted = 0''')  

doneBids = Uqbids.objects.raw('''
                    select DISTINCT uq_main_id as bidDoneUqmain, id  from 
                      uqbids  where created_by = %s''',[request.user.id])
```

here **viewAllUq** and **doneBids** are two raw queries I want to merge this query into one query like

```
merged = viewAllUq + doneBids   #I want something like this to merge them

    for data in merged:
        print(data.companyName)  # Access viewAllUq object data 
        print(data.bidDoneUqmain) # Access doneBids object data
```

I do a few google search but not helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

May be better to use dict for your database queries. Something like:

```
merged_dict ={"viewAllUq":viewAllUq, 
"doneBids": doneBids
}
view_all_uq = merged_dict.get("viewAllUq")
```

And you can iterate by dict if you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. if I do `view_all_uq = merged_dict.get("viewAllUq")` then I can only access viewAllUq data only but I want to access doneBids at the same time.

Comment: Your tables uqmain and uqbids has relation?

Comment: No, they have no relation

Comment: Through other tables they hve not relation?

Comment: I use to act as a foreign key concept. So basically they have no relation. If you print view_all_uq then it only returns viewAllUq full query not doneBids